# Line break in Jade/Express within a conditional

Tags: csv, express, pug

I need to output plain text in a jade layout (using express) and I need it to appear on separate lines like so -

```
Hello
There
World"0"
World"1"
World"2"
```

I would have thought I could do it like this - (jade template coming up)

```
|Hello
|There
- for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
  |World"#{i}"
```

But instead this gives me

```
Hello
ThereWorld"0"World"1"World"2"
```

For the life of me, I cannot understand how to do a line break within a conditional loop! This is not meant to be HTML text, its plain text for CSV binary output, so the breaks are important and so are the double quotes as well as the escaping to prevent tags.

Is it not possible to do this in Jade? I don't have much experience in Jade, so I'd appreciate any help at all from the experts out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
- for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    = World + "\n"
```

Comment: Thanks thats a good step forward! But a few issues with this solution

(1) I need dynamic values in there, and I cant do the #{} within "" anymore, everything gets escaped
(2) because its CSV, I need to wrap my values in double quotes, which just become &quot; now

If this can be solved, we'll be golden!

Sorry I should have been clearer with my original question, but I was trying to aim for a simple example.

Comment: use !{}, it no longer gets escaped

Comment: !{} doesnt seem to work, according to Jade docu, its meant to output unescaped strings - https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a6-3

Comment: I updated my answer. I am at work now, so I cannot test if it works. But it should in theory :)

Comment: Tried this out of curiousity, doesn't seem to work unfortunately. But definitely appreciate the help in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the OP to include dynamic variables and double quotes, the stuff I really need.

Played around with the suggestion from @Amberlamps and came up with this for an answer -

```
|Hello
|There
- for (var i=0; i<3; i++)
  ="\n"
  |World"#{i}"
```

I'm sure there are other variants to this solution, but this one works for me.

If I ever need to do more advanced templating, I'll definitely check out Moustache or Handlebars - Jade and its docu just doesn't do it for me.